# How to format and unformat dollar amounts with comma separator in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have tried to format dollar amount with comma separator in regex below:

```
$.fn.digits = function(){ 
    return this.each(function(){ 
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") ); 
    })
}

<div>$1000000</div>

$('#divid').digits();
```

This is working fine for formatting the amount, but how to unformat the amount field?

Is there someother simple way to do this?

Comment: What does `unformat` mean here? Revert from `$1,000,000` to `$1000000`? Check out `var result = '$1,000,000'.replace(/(\d+),/g, '$1');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all unnecessary chars with `RegEx` and with `.replace` method, like so

```
$.fn.unformat = function(){ 
    return this.each(function() { 
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9$]/g, '')); 
    })
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/atarasyuk/sf03so9y/)

Comment: Have one doubt! If it is with dollars and cents $1003.56, it is formating the cents(56)... and getting only $1003. How to overcome this?